# PyGame Space Invaders Game - Making aliens move together

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I've created a Space Invaders clone in Python using the PyGame modules but I'm running into some difficulty getting them to move down together when reaching the edge of the game screen.

How would I make it so when the aliens reach the edge of the game screen they all simultaneously change direction and drop down a level?

```
import pygame
import random

class spaceInvader(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("spaceInvader.png")
        self.x = 200
        self.y = 390

        self.shots = []

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 5
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x+=dist
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x-=dist

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))
        for s in self.shots:
            s.draw(screen)

class Alien(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,x,y,direction,alienType):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.AlienType = alienType
        self.Direction = direction

        if alienType == 1:
            alienImage = pygame.image.load("alien1.png")
            self.Speed = 1
            self.Score = 5

        if alienType == 2:
            alienImage = pygame.image.load("alien2.png")
            self.Score = 15
            self.Speed = 1

        if alienType == 3:
            alienImage = pygame.image.load("alien3.png")
            self.Score = 10
            self.Speed = 1

        if alienType == 4:
            alienImage = pygame.image.load("alien4.png")
            self.Score = 20
            self.Speed = 1

        if alienType == 5:
            alienImage = pygame.image.load("alien5.png")
            self.Score = 25
            self.Speed = 1

        self.image = pygame.Surface([26, 50])
        self.image.set_colorkey(black)
        self.image.blit(alienImage,(0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def moveAliens(self):
        if self.Direction == "right":
            self.rect.x += self.Speed
        if self.Direction == "left":
            self.rect.x -= self.Speed

pygame.init()

pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([400,400])

allAliens = pygame.sprite.Group()
spaceInvader = spaceInvader()

pygame.display.set_caption("Space Attack")
background_image = pygame.image.load("Galaxy.png").convert()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
black =( 0, 0, 0)
white =( 255,255,255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
score = 0
enemies = []

#For X coords
spawnPositions = [50,100,150,200,250,300,350]

yCoord = 10

for n in range(5):
    for i in range(len(spawnPositions)):
        xCoord = spawnPositions[i] 
        alienType = random.randint(1,5)
        alien = Alien(xCoord, yCoord,"right", alienType)
        allAliens.add(alien)
    yCoord = yCoord + 15

loop = 0
while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    for alien in (allAliens.sprites()):
        if alien.rect.x < 0:
            alien.rect.y = alien.rect.y + 15
            alien.Direction = "right"
        if alien.rect.x > 395:
            alien.rect.y = alien.rect.y + 15
            alien.Direction = "left"
        loop =+1

    for alien in (allAliens.sprites()):
        alien.moveAliens()

    spaceInvader.handle_keys()
    screen.blit(background_image,[0,0])
    spaceInvader.draw(screen)
    allAliens.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(20)

pygame.quit()
```

Thanks.

Comment: For classes, name them with a capital letter for every word. For example `SpaceInvader` instead or `spaceInvader`. For attributes and variables, name them with just lowercase and underscore to separate each word. For example `self.alien_type` instead of `self.AlienType` and `y_coord` instead of `yCoord`. That way your following the Python naming conventions and makes it easier for other programmers to quickly identify what's a class and what's an attribute or variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
for alien in (allAliens.sprites()):
    if alien.rect.x < 0:
        alien.rect.y = alien.rect.y + 15
        alien.Direction = "right"
    if alien.rect.x > 395:
        alien.rect.y = alien.rect.y + 15
        alien.Direction = "left"
    loop =+1
```

I assume the aliens are currently individually dropping down?

You need to change this so that when one alien triggers these if statements, all alien's `y` and `direction` are appropriately set, not just the one hitting the side.

Comment: Indeed they were. Did as you said and added a second for loop, works perfectly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Space Invader
import turtle
import os
import random
import math

# Set up the screen.
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(700,700)
wn.bgcolor("lightblue")

wn.title("Space Invaders")



# Draw border
border = turtle.Turtle()
border.speed("fastest")
border.color("white")
border.penup()
border.setposition(-300,-270)
border.pendown()
border.pensize(3)
for side in range(4):
    border.forward(560)
    border.left(90)
border.hideturtle()

# Set the score to 0.
score = 0

# Draw the score.
score_pen = turtle.Turtle()
score_pen.speed("fastest")
score_pen.color("white")
score_pen.penup()
score_pen.setposition(-290,260)
scorestring = "Score: %s" %score
score_pen.write(scorestring, False, align="left", font = ("Arial",14,"normal"))
score_pen.hideturtle()

# Create the player turtle
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("black")
player.speed("fastest")
player.shape("triangle")
player.penup()
player.setposition(0,-265)
player.setheading(90)


playerspeed = 15

# Create enemy
#enemy = turtle.Turtle()
#enemy.shape("circle")
#enemy.color("red")
#enemy.penup()
#enemy.speed(2)
#enemy.setposition(-200,250)

#enemyspeed = 2

# Choose number of enemies.
number_of_enemies = 5
# Create an empty list of enemies.
enemies = []

# Add enemies to list.
for i in range(number_of_enemies):
    # Create enemy
    enemies.append(turtle.Turtle())

for enemy in enemies:
    enemy.shape("circle")
    enemy.color("red")
    enemy.penup()
    enemy.speed(2)
    x = random.randint(-200,200)
    y = random.randint(100,250)
    enemy.setposition(x,y)

enemyspeed = 2    

# Create the player's bullet.
bullet = turtle.Turtle()
bullet.color("yellow")
bullet.shape("triangle")
bullet.penup()
bullet.speed("fastest")
bullet.setheading(90)
bullet.shapesize(.5,.5)
bullet.hideturtle()

bulletspeed = 20

# Define bullet state
# ready - ready to fire
# fire - bullet is firing
bulletstate = "ready"




# Move the player left and right.
def move_left():
    x = player.xcor()
    x -= playerspeed
    if x < -280:
        x = -280
    player.setx(x)

def move_right():
    x = player.xcor()
    x += playerspeed
    if x >250:
        x = 250
    player.setx(x)

def fire_bullet():
    # Declare the bulletstate as a global if it needs changed.
    global bulletstate
    if bulletstate == "ready":
        bulletstate = "fire"
        # Move the bullet just above the player.
        x = player.xcor()
        y = player.ycor() + 10
        bullet.setposition(x,y)
        bullet.showturtle()

def isCollision(t1,t2):
    dx = t1.xcor() - t2.xcor()
    dy = t1.ycor()- t2.ycor()
    distance = dx**2 + dy**2
    distance1 = math.sqrt(distance)
    if distance1 < 15:
        return True
    else:
        return False



# Create keyboard bindings
wn.onkey(move_left, "Left")
wn.onkey(move_right,"Right")
wn.onkey(fire_bullet,"space")
wn.listen()


# Main game loop
while True:


    for enemy in enemies:

        # Move enemy
        x = enemy.xcor()
        x += enemyspeed
        enemy.setx(x)

        # Move the enemy back and down
        if enemy.xcor()>250:
            # Move all the enemies down
            for e in enemies:
                y = e.ycor()
                y -= 40
                e.sety(y)
            # Change the enemy direction
            enemyspeed *= -1

        if enemy.xcor()< -280:
            # Move all the enemies down
            for e in enemies:
                y = e.ycor()
                y -= 40
                e.sety(y)
            # change the enemy direction
            enemyspeed *= -1
        # Check for the collision between bullet and the enemy.
        if isCollision(bullet ,enemy):
            # Reset the bullet
            bullet.hideturtle()
            bulletstate = "ready"
            bullet.setposition(0,-400)
            # Reset the enemy
            x = random.randint(-200,200)
            y = random.randint(100,250)
            enemy.setposition(x,y)
            # Update the score.
            score += 1
            scorestring = "Score: %s" %score
            score_pen.clear()
            score_pen.write(scorestring, False, align = "left",font = ("Arial",14, "normal"))

        if isCollision(player,enemy):
            player.hideturtle()
            enemy.hideturtle()
            print("Game Over")
            break







    # Move the bullet.
    if bulletstate == "fire":
        y = bullet.ycor()
        y += bulletspeed
        bullet.sety(y)

    # Check to see if the bullet has gone to the top.
    if bullet.ycor() > 275:
        bullet.hideturtle()
        bulletstate = "ready"


turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: The code itself is not a good answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer